# BackgroundWorker and shared class

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a `NumericUpDown` control in the main thread.

I create an instance of a public `class_A` that stores the `NumericUpDown` value.

I create a `BackgroundWorker` that runs a separate thread.

In the `BackgroundWorker` thread I create an instance of a `class_B` that recalls the argument from the instance of `class_A`.

I don't understand why the instance of the `class_A` just created before, its result as `Nothing`.

Here is the code:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents bgw As New BackgroundWorker
    Dim WithEvents bgw2 As New BackgroundWorker
    Dim lSide As Label
    Public nudSide As NumericUpDown
    Dim bCalculate As Button
    Dim bCalculate2 As Button
    Dim tbLog As TextBox
    Dim calc As calc
    Public calc2 As calc2
    Public Delegate Function d_getSide() As Double
    Public getSide As New d_getSide(AddressOf rungetSide)
    Public Side As c_Side
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Size = New Size(400, 160)
        bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        bgw2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

        lSide = New Label
        With lSide
            .Text = "Side"
            .Size = New Size(40, 20)
            .Location = New Point(10, 10)

        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(lSide)
        nudSide = New NumericUpDown
        With nudSide
            .Size = New Size(40, 20)
            .Location = New Point(lSide.Location.X + lSide.Size.Width, lSide.Location.Y)
            .DecimalPlaces = 0
            .Minimum = 1
            .Maximum = 100
            .Increment = 1
            .Value = 1
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(nudSide)
        bCalculate = New Button
        With bCalculate
            .Text = "Calculate"
            .Size = New Size(60, 20)
            .Location = New Point(nudSide.Location.X + nudSide.Size.Width + 40, nudSide.Location.Y)
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf bCalculate_Click
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(bCalculate)
        bCalculate2 = New Button
        With bCalculate2
            .Text = "Calculate 2"
            .Size = New Size(60, 20)
            .Location = New Point(bCalculate.Location.X + bCalculate.Size.Width + 10, bCalculate.Location.Y)
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf bCalculate2_Click
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(bCalculate2)

        tbLog = New TextBox
        With tbLog
            .Size = New Size(250, 60)
            .Location = New Point(lSide.Location.X, lSide.Location.Y + 40)
            .Multiline = True
            .ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical

        End With 
        Me.Controls.Add(tbLog)

    End Sub
    Private Sub bCalculate_Click()
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(nudSide.Value)
    End Sub
    Private Sub bgw_Dowork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
        'example 1)
        'passing argument throught backGroundWorker
        calc = New calc(e.Argument)
    End Sub
    Private Sub bgw_Runworkercompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted
        getResult()
    End Sub
    Private Sub bCalculate2_Click()
        'here i create an instance of the Side class (expose the side property)
        Side = New c_Side
        bgw2.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub
    Private Sub bgw2_Dowork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw2.DoWork
        'example 2)
        ' in the backgroundworker thread i create an instance of the class calc2
        calc2 = New calc2()
    End Sub
    Private Sub bgw2_Runworkercompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw2.RunWorkerCompleted
        getResult2()
    End Sub
    Private Sub write(ByVal message As String)
        With tbLog
            .SelectionStart = .Text.Length
            .SelectedText = vbCrLf & message
        End With
    End Sub
    Private Sub getResult()
        tbLog.Clear()
        write("area = " & calc.area & " cm^2")
        write("volume = " & calc.volume & " cm^3")

    End Sub
    Private Sub getResult2()
        tbLog.Clear()
        write("area = " & calc2.area & " cm^2")
        write("volume = " & calc2.volume & " cm^3")

    End Sub
    Public Function rungetSide() As Double
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(getSide)
        Else
            Return Side.Side
        End If
        Return Side.Side
    End Function
End Class
Class calc
    Sub New(ByVal Side As Double)
        _area = Side ^ 2
        _volume = Side ^ 3
    End Sub
    Private _area As Double
    Public Property area As Double
        Get
            Return Math.Round(_area, 2)
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _area = Math.Round(value, 2)
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _volume As Double
    Public Property volume As Double
        Get
            Return Math.Round(_volume, 2)
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _volume = Math.Round(value, 2)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
Public Class calc2
    Sub New()
        'the constructor, recall the value from the instance (public) of the class 'Side' just built in the main thread
        'but i don't understand why the instance it's nothing
        _area = Form1.Side.Side ^ 2
        _volume = Form1.Side.Side ^ 3
    End Sub
    Private _area As Double
    Public Property area As Double
        Get
            Return Math.Round(_area, 2)
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _area = Math.Round(value, 2)
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _volume As Double
    Public Property volume As Double
        Get
            Return Math.Round(_volume, 2)
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _volume = Math.Round(value, 2)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
Public Class c_Side
    Sub New()
        _Side = Form1.nudSide.Value
        '_Side = Form1.rungetSide
    End Sub
    Private _Side As Double
    Public Property Side As Double
        Get
            Return Math.Round(_Side, 2)
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Side = Math.Round(value, 2)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

What I'm looking for is to create an instance of `class_A` in the main thread and store the `NumericUpDown` value, and in a separate thread (`BackgroundWorker`) create an instance of `class_B` and obtain the value of the `NumericUpDown` control, just before stored in the instance of `class_A`.

Comment: @SirRufo: please don't do trivial edits like removing a single tag, especially on relatively new posts where someone else is likely working on an edit that actually improves the post significantly. If you feel you need to edit the post, edit _everything_ that needs editing. Otherwise, you disrupt the edit in progress, forcing it to be redone.

Comment: sorry..??I never edits my message

Comment: `Form1.nudSide`.  Sigh, VB.NET was designed to ensure that a VB.NET programmer can never write threaded code correctly.  That expression creates a *new* instance of the Form1 class when it is called from a worker thread.  Never access UI components from a worker thread.  Note how you did it right in bCalculate_Click().

Comment: Marcello, Peter wasn't talking to you :). He typed `@SirRufo` in the beginning which means he's notifying the user called `Sir Rufo`.

Comment: Thanks Vincent i understand

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant for you reply, in the bCalculate_Click, i pass to the backGroundWorker thread the argument (in the backGroundWorker 'argument' property), but in another program i have a class with a constructor, that build another class with another constructor, that build another class with another constructor that need some form.controls value, and i don't like to pass throught 3 class constructor an argument that it's only a control value, so i want to store the UI control value somewhere and call it from the backGroundWorker thread. Did you know if is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I've found the  solution.
Just declare the variable as Public Shared

```
Public Shared Side As c_Side
```

So it's visible from all the application, and so, from all the threads.
So when i start the thread (or when i want or when i need), i backup all the values of the UI controls in a Public Shared instance of a Public Class, that can be 'read' from the backGroundWorker thread.